# Android: gson.toJson converter giving empty string for Android objects

Tags: java, android, json, object, gson

I'm trying to covert Java object to json using Gson library, but its not working as expected and returning empty string,

my code:

```
String ie = new String("Jack");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String intentcalue = gson.toJson(ie);
```

it returns:
{}

Please let me know if anything wrong with library, I tried with other Objects as well all returning null value like for Intent Object, ApplicationInfo etc

Comment: What result are you expected?

Comment: Results are expected something like this for intent object 
{"mAction":"android.intent.action.MAIN","mContentUserHint":-2,"mFlags":0}

Comment: Random guess: your `String` is imported from a package other than `java.lang`? Normally, Gson never converts strings (`"..."`) to JSON object literals (`{}`) just like you provided.

Answer (score -1):

If you want convert string to json object, your string must be json as well.
For example:

```
String ie = new String("{\"name\": \"Jack\"}");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String intentcalue = gson.toJson(ie);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, Can help me with other java objects like       
    Intent ie = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

Comment: Downvoted. The OP did the same.

Comment: @AKS Never, never, and one more never do that for classes you don't control. Everything from the `android.` package is out of your control, `Intent` either. Hence, serialize your DTO class designed for that very purpose, say `public final class MyCoolDtoClassHoldingAllNecessaryIntentData { public final String action; ... }`.

Comment: Thank you @fluffy , is there any way i can convert Such objects to Json String?

Comment: @AKS Well, sure, what else Gson is designed for? Please refer the `Gson` class documentation at https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html , especially the `toJson` overloads.